# Cordova load external content from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

There are many (nearly) similar questions, but none of them solved my issue.

I'm writing a cordova app (currently only testing on andoid and ios), and want to load data (in JSON-format) from my webserver. I use jQuerys `$.ajax` - method for that.

My code so far:

```
$.support.cors = true;
var ret = -1;
$.ajax(url, {
    traditional: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },
    data: dataString,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Data recieved:');
        alert(data);
        ret = data;
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
        alert('There was an error');
        alert(error);
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
return ret;
```

This works on browsers (tested in latest Firefox), but not in the app. The error seems to be about cross origin page loading.

My config.xml looks like this:

```
...
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
...
```

The server is accepting cors-requests via header (otherwise it probably wouldn't work in the browser):

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
...
```

but stil: cordova doesn't want to load anything. The `alert(error);` - line shows this:

> SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 'https://myHost.com/?someparams=foo' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy

What problem has cordova with this?

Comment: have you tried setting the meta tag in the index.html of your application to allow for access to the url you want?

Comment: No, I didn't know that you also had to do that in the html file. Can you provide me an example on how to do this?

Comment: I had to the same for an ionic app, and I remember it needed the CSP to work. ICheck the answer I added. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer of `@toskv`. Check if your HTML-Pages in Cordova include following meta-tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`. The meta-tag is added by Cordova by default and prevents CORS from working (as you can see only `self` is allowed for `default-src`).

Use the links from `@toskv` to learn more.

> The readme of **[cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)** has more examples.
>
> More info about the Content Security Policy meta tag can be found [here](http://content-security-policy.com/).

Comment: That was it! There was actually already this meta-tag... I guess you should sometimes go to bed earlier and look at the problem again the next day :)

Answer (score 4):

You might have to set the **Content Security Policy** in index.html to allow for requests towards the domain hosting your services.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' <enter-your-domain-here> data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com;">
```

The readme of **[cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)** has more examples.

More info about the Content Security Policy meta tag can be found [here](http://content-security-policy.com/).

Comment: This code doesnt seem to work, and additionally it blocks the eval function, which would force me to refactor my code :/

All i want is to enable the communication to one host, no additional security rules.

Sadly i don't really understand the readmy. Could you help me once more? How would that meta tag look like then?

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope that helps. Also you might want to set the withCredentials field to true. :)

Comment: Hey, I noticed that for me the problem was that the meta tag was in there by default. If you remove the meta tag everything works like a charm!